# How to center text in custom "square" TextView

Tags: android

I've create a custom TextView because I want:

- its height to match certain constraints (top to top and bottom to bottom of another TextView)
- its width matching that height so the oval shape xml set as background of the TextView shows a circle.

Here's the code of the custom View:

```
public class SquareTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    public static final String TAG = "SquareTextView";
    int squareDim = 0;

    public SquareTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int h = this.getMeasuredHeight();
        int w = this.getMeasuredWidth();
        squareDim = Math.max(w, h);

        setMeasuredDimension(squareDim, squareDim);
    }
}
```

layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_registration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="WW-WWW"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_aircraft_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MMMMMMMMM"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_registration"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_registration" />

        <com.mydomain.SquareTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_registration"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cv_ops_restrictions"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

shape_circle.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <size android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

Problem is that I want the text centered in the circle. Any pointers on how to achieve this or on what I'm doing wrong? at the moment it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: can you post your circle drawable as well? I just copied your code and it looks perfect.

Comment: added the circle shape :)

Comment: https://ibb.co/jFfnmH Am I missing on something? because you have given gravity correctly. Its working fine.

Comment: hum, yes ... that's how I want it to look. Can you try and make the SquareView's height greater, maybe just by spacing the 2 left TextViews more?

Comment: Please use `MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)` to read the dimension, and don't use `widthMeasureSpec` directly. It has bitflags encoded and is not a "pure" dimension that you can just use. With the maximum dimension you then use `MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(max, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)` to create the measure spec that you pass to `setMeasuredDimension`

Comment: Thx David, I'll give that a try (just for the sake of knowing why my first solution didn't work! ^^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to recommend that you don't use a custom `TextView` subclass at all here. You're already working inside `ConstraintLayout`, which supports aspect ratios for its children. That means you can replace `<com.mydomain.SquareTextView>` with `<TextView>` and add this attribute to get a perfect square view:

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
```

Comment: @kazume it wasn't clear to me whether you want the circle's size to be defined by its width or its height; if you want it to fill up all the space between its top and bottom constraints, change the `layout_width` attribute to `0dp`.

Comment: Took my a few tries to figure that one out, but indeed that's the answer I'm looking for! Thx a lot :)